# Leaving the dictation mode with a voice command

Tags: voice-recognition

Is there any way to leave the dictation mode with a voice command, without having to tap anywhere in Android 4 or above?

[image]

I use the built in speech recognition program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can leave the dictation mode with a voice command on Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.  The command is `stop`.

[image]